# Inconsistent vector representation using transformers BertModel and BertTokenizer

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I have a `BertTokenizer` (`tokenizer`) and a `BertModel` (`model`) from the `transformers` library.
**I have pre-trained the model from scratch** with a few wikipedia articles, just to test how it works.

Once the model is pre-trained, **I want to extract a layer vector representation for a given sentence**. For that, I calculate the average of the 11 hidden (768-sized) vectors. I do this as follows (`line` is a single `String`):

```
padded_sequence = tokenizer(line, padding=True)
        
indexed_tokens = padded_sequence['input_ids']
attention_mask = padded_sequence["attention_mask"]

tokens_tensor = torch.tensor([indexed_tokens])
attention_mask_tensor = torch.tensor([attention_mask])

outputs = model(tokens_tensor, attention_mask_tensor)
hidden_states = outputs[0]

line_vectorized = hidden_states[0].data.numpy().mean(axis=0)
```

So far so good. **I can do this for every sentence individually. But now I want to do it in batch**, ie. I have a bunch of sentences and instead of iterating each sentence I send the appropiate tensor representations to get all vectors at once. I do this as follows (`lines` is a `list of Strings`):

```
padded_sequences = self.tokenizer_PYTORCH(lines, padding=True)
        
indexed_tokens_list = padded_sequences['input_ids']
attention_mask_list = padded_sequences["attention_mask"]
        
tokens_tensors_list = [torch.tensor([indexed_tokens]) for indexed_tokens in indexed_tokens_list]
attention_mask_tensors_list = [torch.tensor([attention_mask ]) for attention_mask in attention_mask_list ]
        
tokens_tensors = torch.cat((tokens_tensors_list), 0)
attention_mask_tensors = torch.cat((attention_mask_tensors_list ), 0)

outputs = model(tokens_tensors, attention_mask_tensors)
hidden_states = outputs[0]

lines_vectorized = [hidden_states[i].data.numpy().mean(axis=0) for i in range(0, len(hidden_states))]
```

The problem is the following: **I have to use padding so that I can appropiately concatenate the token tensors**. That means that the indexed tokens and the attention masks can be larger than in the previous case where the sentences were evaluated individually. **But when I use padding, I get different results for the sentences which have been padded**.

*EXAMPLE*:
I have two sentences (in French but it doesn't matter):

`sentence_A` = "appareil digestif un article de wikipedia l encyclopedie libre"

`sentence_B` = "sauter a la navigation sauter a la recherche cet article est une ebauche concernant la biologie"

When I evaluate the two sentences **individually**, I obtain:

`sentence_A`:

```
indexed_tokens =  [10002, 3101, 4910, 557, 73, 3215, 9630, 2343, 4200, 8363, 10000]
attention_mask =  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
line_vectorized =  [-0.9304411   0.53798294 -1.6231083 ...]
```

`sentence_B`:

```
indexed_tokens =  [10002, 2217, 6496, 1387, 9876, 2217, 6496, 1387, 4441, 405, 73, 6451, 3, 2190, 5402, 1387, 2971, 10000]
attention_mask =  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
line_vectorized =  [-0.8077076   0.56028104 -1.5135447  ...]
```

But when I evaluate the two sentences **in batch**, I obtain:

`sentence_A`:

```
indexed_tokens =  [10002, 3101, 4910, 557, 73, 3215, 9630, 2343, 4200, 8363, 10000, 10004, 10004, 10004, 10004, 10004, 10004, 10004]
attention_mask =  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
line_vectorized =  [-1.0473819   0.6090186  -1.727466  ...]
```

`sentence_B`:

```
indexed_tokens =  [10002, 2217, 6496, 1387, 9876, 2217, 6496, 1387, 4441, 405, 73, 6451, 3, 2190, 5402, 1387, 2971, 10000]
attention_mask =  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
line_vectorized =  [-0.8077076   0.56028104 -1.5135447  ...]
```

That is, **since `sentence_B` is larger than `sentence_A`, `sentence_A` has been padded and the attention mask has been padded with zeros as well**. The indexed tokens contain now extra tokens (`10004` which I assume `empty`).
The vector representation of `sentence_B` has NOT changed. But **the vector representation of `sentence_A` HAS CHANGED**.

I would like to know if this is working as intended or not (I assume not).
And I guess I am doing something wrong but I can't figure out what.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do it in single sentence per batch, the maximum length of the sentence is maximum number of tokens, however, when you do it in batch the maximum length of the sentences remains the same across the batch, which defaults to the maximum number of tokens in the longest sentence. The max values of `1` in this case indicates its not a `<PAD>` token, and `0` indicates a `<PAD>` token. The best way to control this is to define the maximum sequence length and truncate the sentences longer than the maximum sequence length.

This can be done using an alternative method to tokenize the text in batches (a single sentence can be considered as batch-size of 1):

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("<your bert model>", do_lower_case=True)
encoding = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(lines, return_tensors='pt',padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=50, add_special_tokens = True) ## Change the max_length to the required max length
indexed_tokens = encoding['input_ids']
attention_mask = encoding['attention_mask']
```

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't help. The problem is that I get different vectors whenever a given indexed_token is padded and I add the corresponding zeros to the attention_mask. Regardless of how that token has been obtained.

Comment: I have updated the answer, do let me know if its useful.